# Uniswap exchanges at wrong price?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, price

The current state of WETH-DAI pool on Ropsten is (33796288305479532646, 31012471784612084535765) with it 0.01% fee. So, 1 WETH = 917 DAI.

Why Uniswap exchanges the pair at 1 WETH : 494 DAI ?

Answer (score 2):

The prices on decentralized exchanges can be changed only through token swaps. On the mainnet, there is a constant stream of arbitrage transactions, mostly by bots, that keep the prices similar between CEX and DEX. On testnets, there are no financial incentives for arbitrage, so they don't get done, and prices are kind of random as a result.

Comment: I think the prices on both mainnet and testnet are based on the liquidity of the pools at the moment the swaps are made.

Comment: @notooth Incorrect. For xy=k type of automated market makers, the price P is defined as P=y/x. Liquidity determines the price impact (delta) when a swap is made, not the price itself.

Comment: Can you let me know specifically in numbers the DAI I should get if I send 1 WETH to the pool?

Comment: @notooth that's a separate question that may already be answered on the site, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674345/how-execution-price-is-calculated-in-uniswap

Comment: Read the [help] to better understand how QA on Stack Overflow works.